# How to install an open through another app?

Tags: android

i am making an app that will instal an apk. file on to the phone by the click of a button. Does anyone know how to do this?

EXAMPLE

APP 1 -

Button1 clicked = Install APP2.apk

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the installer activity to install your APK for you:

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your/program.apk"), 
                                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```